# How to create list of threads in PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I write an application which I would like to start computation in separate threads after clicking button "Start". Each time button is pushed separate computation should start in separate thread. Till now I figured out to run computation in separate thread but only once. My idea is to create a list to which threads will be append and start. But I realy dont have any idea how to do it. Can any one help me with this issue and present some basic code on which I can learn how to do it?? The rule is one click one computation(thread), next click next computation(thread) etc...

Regards
Prada

Comment: Here's a similar question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590055/run-multiple-qthreads-concurrently-in-python/29665922

Comment: No worries, feel free to up vote ;)